# How to apply color balance from one image to another

Tags: python, image-processing

I've got  two images, the first one contain multiple items, which shows true colors. Then when I removed most of the item, then the webcam tried to auto-balance the image and yielded really false color.

Is there a way (in code) to apply the color profile of the first (true-color) image to the second image?

(or point me to some keywords, I'm new to the field, thanks)

Attached them here for easy comparison

True color
[image]

Falsely-adjusted color
[image]

I used Logitech webcam, which I can't figure out how to turn off auto-balance in code (in Linux).

Comment: Perhaps something like this may help: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/

Answer (score 0):

I use this method and it works very well:

```
#pip install color_transfer 

from color_transfer import color_transfer

# Load the two images
img1 = cv2.imread('image12.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('image1.png')


# Apply the color transfer
img2_transferred = color_transfer(img1, img2)

cv2.imshow("image", img2_transferred)
if cv2.waitKey(0) == chr("q"):
    exit(0)
```